# ¿Cómo puedo generar a través de la base de datos un link dinámicamente?

Tags: php, mysql

Encontré este código en **YouTube**, pero lo hice de otra forma, y me devuelve un error. La tabla solo tiene esos 2 campos:

```php
<?php
require('conexion.php');

$sentencia="SELECT * FROM menu";
$insercion=mysqli_query($conexion,$sentencia);
$array = mysqli_fetch_array($insercion);
?>

<?php for ($i=0; $i <sizeof($array) ; $i++) { ?>
<a href="<?php echo $array[$i]['link'] ?>"><?php echo $array[$i]['nombre']?></a>
<?php } ?>
```

Este es el error devuelto:

```
Warning: Illegal string offset 'nombre' in C:\xampp\htdocs\Pruebas\index.php on line 29
p
Warning: Illegal string offset 'nombre' in C:\xampp\htdocs\Pruebas\index.php on line 29
h
Notice: Undefined offset: 2 in C:\xampp\htdocs\Pruebas\index.php on line 29
Notice: Undefined offset: 3 in C:\xampp\htdocs\Pruebas\index.php on line 29
```

Comment: Pon en tu código esto: `var_dump($array);`  y dinos qué muestra.

Comment: Me sale esto array(4) { [0]=> string(9) "index.php" ["link"]=> string(9) "index.php" [1]=> string(5) "lucas" ["nombre"]=> string(5) "lucas" } lucas lucas lucas lucas @A.Cedano

Comment: Prueba con `$array = mysqli_fetch_all($insercion, MYSQLI_ASSOC);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si observamos el contenido de `$array` veremos varias cosas:

```
array(4) { 
    [0]=> string(9) "index.php" 
    ["link"]=> string(9) "index.php" 
    [1]=> string(5) "lucas" 
    ["nombre"]=> string(5) "lucas" 
}
```

1. Hay datos repetidos. Esto es porque `mysqli_fetch_array` te organiza los datos en el array con una clave numérica y de forma asociativa usando los nombres de columna de la tabla. No hay ninguna necesidad de tener dos veces `index.php`, `lucas`, etc.
2. No puedes leer el array del modo en que lo estás haciendo, porque no tienes realmente uno o más arrays dentro de otro array. Es decir, lo que haría funcionar tu actual código sería esta estructura:

   ```
   array(1) {
     [0]=>
     array(4) {
       [0]=>
       string(5) "index"
       [1]=>
       string(5) "lucas"
       ["link"]=>
       string(5) "index"
       ["nombre"]=>
       string(5) "lucas"
     }
   }
   ```

   Pero no es eso lo que tienes y por eso todos los errores.

Es más simple de lo que parece:

1. Para solventar lo primero que te he señalado, usaremos un método más específico.
2. Para solventar el problema del bucle, usaremos una lectura simple. Dado que necesitas imprimir los datos in-situ lo haremos con un `while` aplicado sobre el método fetch. Es el modo habitual si revisas los ejemplos del Manual de PHP y la mayoría de ejemplos en Stackoverflow y en la mayoría de sitios web. Al mismo tiempo aprovecharemos para evitar la horrible mezcla de bloques PHP/HTML.

Este sería el código propuesto:

```
<?php 
  require('conexion.php');
  $sentencia="SELECT * FROM menu";
  $insercion=mysqli_query($conexion,$sentencia);
  $html="";
  while( $row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($insercion)) {
    $html.="<a href=\"$row[link]\">$row[nombre]</a>";
  }
  echo $html;
```

Si tienes alguna duda pregunta en comentarios.